# Install4J will not launch an application if installed with Admin user

Tags: java, install4j

We are trying to install our Eclipse RCP application with admin user permissions.
It picks up default directory of C:\Program_Files<Path given in media options> during installation.
Our requirement is to have unattended installation and user should not get a chance to pick up directory.

However as normal users do not have necessary permissions to directory C:\Program_Files<Path given in media options>, our application will not launch.

Is there anyway to configure default directory of installation to logged in user space than C:\Program_Files<...> by default?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a "Run script" action to the "Startup" node of your installer and use your own logic to set the installation directory, for example with the script

```
if (context.isUnattended() && Util.isWindows() && !Util.hasFullAdminRights()) {
    context.setInstallationDirectory(
        new File((String)context.getVariable("sys.localAppdataDir"), "myApp")
    );
}
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks Ingo for quick response. I will try this solution and confirm.

Comment: This solution worked. Thanks @Ingo Kegel for this fix.